# Azure Policy for Multiple tags unexpected behavior

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I am trying to set up an Azure Policy to enforce multiple tags on a Resource Group upon creation. However, the policy is behaving in a weird manner such that the RG group will get created even when only one of the tags (tagName1) is added. I'm not exactly sure what is going wrong because as per my understanding **allOf** behaves as an AND operator and the RG group should only get created if all the tags have been added.

I need some guidance on how I can debug this. Thanks

My Policy:

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName1'), ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName2'), ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName3'), ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName4'), ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName5'), ']')]",
          "exists": "false"
        },
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "tagName1": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      }
    },
    "tagName2": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      }
    },
    "tagName3": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      }
    },
    "tagName4": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      }
    },
    "tagName5": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Tag Name",
        "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current condition will deny create/update request only if all tags (1-5) don't exist.

Use **anyOf** instead of allOf.

Comment: Yes, I want to deny the resource creation if tags (1-5) do not exist. Basically, my aim is that a RG should not be created without tags (1-5). That's what allOf should do, right?

Comment: Your condition will deny requests only if all tags don't exist. If at least one of the tags 1-5 is provided then your condition won't deny the request. Use anyOf instead of allOf to get what you are aiming to achieve.